# Return from all loops and return value

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin project I need if `volume != null` to exit from `getRecognizedVolume` with `volume`.

I use this:

```
fun getRecognizedVolume(firebaseVisionText: FirebaseVisionText): Double? {
        var countLines = 0
        for (block in firebaseVisionText.textBlocks) {
            for (line in block.lines) {
                val lineText = line.text
                val lineTextToCheck = lineText.trim().toUpperCase()
                val volume = getVolumeValue(lineTextToCheck)
                if (volume != null) {
                    return volume
                }
            }
        } 
      // do some another code
        return volume
    }
```

But I think it's not correct. Because after `return volume` then continue to loop outer loop: `for (block in firebaseVisionText.textBlocks)`

I need when `volume!= null` than **immediately** exit from function with result (**volume**)

How I can fix this?

Comment: There is no "after return volume" the whole function is over at that point. What exactly is not working as it should be?

Comment: Is it possible to `break` a loop execution in Kotlin?

Comment: Maybe you have the second call of this function? `return volume` is the end of all loops in this function. You can run code with debugger to see this behavior

Comment: @deHaar, yes it has `break @label` for exit from nested loops

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html

Comment: @Axifive ok, thanks... But is seems `break` doesn't work in `forEach` but in enhanced `for` loops (and possibly classic ones).

Comment: @deHaar i think break would not do what OP says he wants though, based on what he described he wants to return like he is doing... Not sure why it isnt working for him

Comment: pleae don't modify your question after you have answers

Answer (score 2):

Edit: **The code in the question should work correctly as it doesn't matter how deep nested a `return` statement is, when executed it will take you out of current function.** ***When I first read the question I mistook the `return` for a `break` and hence I posted the below answer.***

***Use following solution*** if you don't want to return right away, but instead ***want to `break` out of all `loops` and then `continue` with your `function`.***

Just as java kotlin also provides [labled breaks](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html), what you have to do is as soon as you find a volume value you set it in a local variable and then `break` out of outer `loop`. After that just `return` the volume. ***if loop didn't break then it will have default null value otherwise the one you set***.

Your code would look something as follows.

```
fun getRecognizedVolume(firebaseVisionText: FirebaseVisionText): Double? {
        var countLines = 0
        var volume: Double? = null 
        outerLoop@ for (block in firebaseVisionText.textBlocks) {
            for (line in block.lines) {
                val lineText = line.text
                val lineTextToCheck = lineText.trim().toUpperCase()
                getVolumeValue(lineTextToCheck)?.let{
                    volume = it
                    break@outerLoop
                }
            }
        } 
        // do something else
        return volume
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that labeling loop will solve the issue as it's do the same thing `return` done!

Answer (score 0):

this work:

```
fun myFunction(): String {
        Debug.d(TAG, "myFunction: start")
        val list_1 = listOf<String>("A", "B", "C")
        val list_2 = listOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        for (item in list_1) {
            Debug.d(TAG, "myFunction: outer_current_item = $item")
            for (innterItem in list_2) {
                Debug.d(TAG, "myFunction: -> current_item = $item, innterItem = $innterItem")
                if (innterItem == 3) {
                    Debug.d(TAG, "myFunction: return_ONLY_hello")
                    return "Hello"
                }
            }
        }
        // do some another many logic
        Debug.d(TAG, "myFunction: FINISH")
        return "Bye"
    }
```

and here output:

```
myFunction: start                                     
myFunction: outer_current_item = A                    
myFunction: -> current_item = A, innterItem = 1       
myFunction: -> current_item = A, innterItem = 2       
myFunction: -> current_item = A, innterItem = 3       
myFunction: return_ONLY_hello
```

as you can see only

```
 return "Hello"
```

is enough to **immediately** exit from `myFunction` with result